# If git repository is down then how to switch native property files automatically in spring cloud config server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to set my spring boot cloud config server to read properties from git repository. But if git is down then it should read from local repository property files. Can anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir = your/path/folder
Using this, if your app has been able to connect once to git, it will create
the specified directory and clone the files from git as fallback.
When your git repository will be unreachable the app config server will use those files.

Also there is this spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start = true/false.
If this is true when the application restarts the folder contents will be deleted and cloned again. You might want to set this to false if you want the files to be kept between restarts. Also if you want to have the fallback available before the first start, you just have to clone the git project locally, and put that path as the basedir.